# Do Ethernet smart scales exist?

Tags: ethernet

I have noticed that my Withings Body+ seems to be reporting measurements quite slowly; 14 hours on some occasions. It is likely that this is because it is not getting a strong WiFi signal, something that is made more probable since we have a very Ethernet orientated house. I am very much an Ethernet guy as you set it up once and then it never gives you any further problems, which cannot be said for WiFi - yay [ethernetmasterrace](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethernetmasterrace/) lol!

As I see it, I therefore have two options to guarantee that this item has connectivity.

1. Put a WiFi access point right next to the scales.
2. Buy new scales that connect via Ethernet.

Due to my disdain for WiFi, I do not really like the former option as it feels like it is more treating the symptom than the root cause. Equally, it would mean putting a Wireless access point in the bathroom, which would a) increase my power consumption and b) require running *Ethernet* there anyway!

Regarding the latter option, I have not been able to find smart bathroom scales that can connect via Ethernet. I get that most consumers are not as obsessed/nerdy as I am so the demand is perhaps a bit less, but surely this is a thing, right? Do you know of a model of smart bathroom scales that is Ethernet compatible?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's unlikely you'll find a set of consumer scales that work with Ethernet as bathrooms don't normally get a patch socket. You might find some industrial scales, but 1) they will be likely be large enough to take a palette 2) not be connected to any app/health tracking service.

Comment: what exactly is a `smart` bathroom scale?

Comment: @jsotola one that allows me to automatically record measurements. I don't mind where.

Comment: You’ll have a hard time finding an Ethernet connected scale. However there are plenty of Bluetooth connected scales available for sale. These will also integrate nicely with eg apps on your smartphone

Comment: The Withings Body+ already has Bluetooth and WiFi, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Quick update - I went with improving my WiFi and all appears to be well now. I still prefer ethernet, but you work with what you've got :D